# How the skip connections occur in resnet50 architecture when input output layers are different?

Tags: conv-neural-network, residual-networks

I am having difficulty understanding how the skip connections occur in resnet50 when the input and output layers are different in shape.

For example, in the first residual block, a **56*56*64** size matrix needs to be added with **56*56*256** size matrix. In the paper they mentioned when input output size are different, they do a projection. They gave the formula, `y = F(x, {Wi}) + Ws*x`
Does that mean do we need to initialize a random matrix of size **64*256** and do a matrix multiplication of `matmul(x, Ws)` so that we get a matrix of **56*56*256** size and then add it with the earlier **56*56*256**  matrix ? Is my understanding correct ?

But in that case how the identity mapping will happen. Aren't we going to lose the identity because we are already multiplying `x` with `Ws` ?